# safest way to process POST actions

Tags: php, html, forms

This is the way i'm currently handling my POST submit actions:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
//several form fields 
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="save" />
```

then on the processing page i have something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['ok']) && $_POST['ok']=="save")
{
    //process the action, and possibly save to database
}
```

now i'm fearing a malicious person might do this(from a script on their website)

```
<form action="http://www.mysite.com/process.php" method="post">
//he can "view source" on my site, view the fields i'm having and put them
//then put the submit button
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="save" />
```

of course with this you see i will be in some hot soup. 
so what can i do, or what is the safest way of handling and processing POST submit actions?

Comment: Restrict domain access to your `process.php` script > http://www.novia.net/~tomcat/HowTo/domainrestric.html

Comment: Which part is the "hot soup" exactly?

Comment: Hence the first rule of programming: never trust user input. You should validate that each input you get has the expected value/range/format.

Comment: If he changes the source to another site it will not be posted to your script thus nothing will hapen ?

Comment: @Carlos, that wasn't the question.

Comment: pretty much all forms are written exactly like this..

Comment: use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to getting the fererer  url

Comment: @DarkBee huh? If he sets the form action, it will call `process.php` on the OP's server...

Comment: @sonusindhu `HTTP_REFERER` can be easily forged.

Comment: easiest way is to check referrer value of request before processing data. where request came from page from where it should come or came from another source.

Comment: if i have a page for "registering new members", which is restricted to, say, admins only, a person can create the fields on their website and redirect to my page for processing..

Comment: @BenM i see. I misinterpreted the code :)

Comment: may be lets not focus our answer on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`, we can try exploring other avenues

Comment: @GThuo on the "register new member" page you should check that the current user is authenticated and authorized to be there. If it passes both things (authentication is not authorization), then proceed with the form data. Also, use tokens to avoid CSRF attacks (see quentin's answer).

Comment: okey i will quickly look at that.

Answer (score 4):

There are two potential problems here.

## Stopping Mallory from making malicious requests to Bob's website

1. Authenticate the user (with OAuth, a username and password, or whatever)
2. Check that the authenticated user is Authorised to do whatever the request is asking for before proceeding with it

## Stopping Mallory from tricking Alice into making a malicious request to Bob's website

This is a [CSRF attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). [Defend against](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) it with a nonse.

Comment: This reminds me to my math classes about RSA / AES. Is it always Bob and Alice ? :D

Comment: this should help me i believe..i will get back to you

Comment: but the "Defense strategy" suggested above seem to be from the browser's side, not the develoer's side

Comment: about tokens, you mean may be getting a hidden field containing some uniquely generated id which i will test on the processing page?

Comment: It's a combined approach. You store an randomly generated token in a session and in the page. The user's browser submits the form (with the token as a hidden field) and you compared the submitted one with the one in the session. Mallory doesn't know the token so can't make a fake form containing it.

Answer (score 2):

You're viewing the problem at the wrong level. Of course you should first  make sure that whoever makes the request (you have a session, right?) has the required privileges to do so. There is nothing in an HTML form that prevents them from doing what you describe so you need to make sure that those who submit the form actually can do so.

(Technically you could check the Referrer, but that is brittle at best).